# Why is filling a new Array so much faster with a while loop?

Tags: javascript, performance

I was considering ways to create arrays containing a default value using native methods and ended up with

```
function pushMap(length, fill){
    var a = [], b = [];
    a.length = length;
    b.push.apply(b,a);
    return b.map(function(){return fill;});
}
```

Expecting it to be **2** or **3** times slower than a while loop, as the native methods have to loop twice whereas while loops only once, so I compared it on [**jsperf**](http://jsperf.com/make-filled-array) against

```
function whileLengthNew(len, val) {
    var rv = new Array(len);
    while (--len >= 0) {
        rv[len] = val;
    }
    return rv;
}
```

and it is actually **18** to **27** times slower (tested with Google Chrome on Ubuntu, browsers/OSs welcome).

What is happening that causes such a big difference?

Comment: Is it correct that you iterate two times over the complete array (one time when calling `push` and one time when calling `map`)?

Comment: `[].push.apply([], new Array(len))` is a strange way to create an array of arbitrary length, initialized with `undefined` values, just to get `map` to work… Needs at least some comments :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would expect that this is due to two major factors:

1. Memory allocation -- `whileLengthNew` creates an array of the correct size first, and then operates on it, `pushMap` creates the final array one element at a time with `map`. This may cause multiple allocations, especially if the source array is large. (The way that you create the initial `a` and `b` arrays is basically irrelevant, since `map` is building up a new array to return anyway -- it doesn't actually change anything in `b`)
2. Function call overhead -- in your call to `map`, you are calling a function for every element of the array. This involves quite a lot of overhead; setting up activation records and scope chains, stack manipulation, and passing the return value back. -- all of this to access a variable which is constant within the function. On top of that, you have set up a closure, so even *accessing* the `fill` variable is slower than it is in the `whileLengthNew` version.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no javascript expert, I didn't contribute to any javascript engines, so the following is just a guess:

In your `pushMap` function you have a lot going on.
 1. First you're expanding `var a` to the size you want in a presumably really inefficient way.  `length` is just a property on the array, so either the underlying implementation has callbacks for when the property is changed, or the underlying implementation can handle the length attribute changing and going with it the next time something in it is accessed.
 2. Creating `var b` seems even more inefficient because you're calling a reflection type method `apply` to make `b` an array of a particular length.
 3. You're then calling basically a foreach loop in a functional way, which will probably be a little slower than a while loop just because of the overhead of the inner function (closure I guess because it's JS)

You may get a more even result if you created `var b` the same way you create `var rv`. Hope this helps. *EDIT* which of course doesn't work in this situation because map only works on initialized values of the array.  Which means another reason this approach is slower (and the OP mentioned this in his question) you are initializing the map twice, once with empty values and again with the values you want.

Comment: You can't `map` over `new Array(len)` because it doesn't actually get any properties set.

Comment: Yeah... I was just testing and realize that of course the reason you are doing the apply first is because map only works on the already initialized values, they are just not initialized to what you want... So in addition to 1 and 2, you are also just initializing your array twice.

Answer (score 0):

You making unnecessary function call for every single value so JavaScript virtual machine has a difficulty optimizing this pattern also your array will not  be treated as a simple array internally but as much complex data structure, in your while loop on the other hand you using very simple array access pattern and I suspect if you will use a for loop with rv.length as a stopping condition it will be faster still

Answer (score 0):

I think calling map() does the same as the while loop does, plus in addition does a function call at each iteration. In general function calls are very slow.