# Faster loop in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I want to update all object child values with the same value, let's do it by code:

```
var days = [
   {
      title: 'Day 1',
      checked: false
   },
   {
      title: 'Day 2',
      checked: true
   },
   {
      title: 'Day 3',
      checked: false
   }
];
```

Now if I want to updates the property `checked` for all days array nodes, I do this:

```
$.each(days, function(i, day) {
   day[i].checked = true;
});
```

So, I'm looking for a better way for doing this, something like this:

```
days[*].checked = true;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the array has hundreds of nodes, I think the loop will be less performance, if I have to do this several times in my App.

Comment: In my opinion every technique has to iterate over your days .so you current approach is good

Comment: If you really eager to optimize performance: [**Helpful Article**](http://jsperf.com/caching-array-length/4) & Avoid `$.each( ... )`

Comment: If you really care about performance, don't use jQuery for loop. Although it's micro optimization anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I've already mentioned comment below the Question! `$.each( ... )` is very costly for the performance. Though it can be only detected at large amount of data in an Array!

And as per [**This Article**](http://jsperf.com/caching-array-length/4) :
And this [***Question***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465251/why-is-filling-a-new-array-so-much-faster-with-a-while-loop)...

> Most light-weight and easy to use way is **While loop**:

```
var len = arr.length;
while (len--) {
  arr[len] *= 2;
}
```

> Then another preferable and more treditional is **do-while loop**:

```
var len = arr.length;
do {
  arr[len] *= 2;
} while (len--);
```

> Least preferable is **Array map** :

```
arr.map(function(el) {
  return el * 2;
});
```

[image]

And there are many other ways to loop through array and are costly than above couple of methods.

***After Edit:***

Disadvantages of `$.each()` loop :

1. Lower performance compare to other loops (for games/animations/large datasets)
2. Less control over iterator (skip items, splice items from list, etc).
3. Dependency on `jQuery` library unlike for, while etc loops!
4. Not familiar syntax, as most other similar languages.

Comment: Thanks, so the `$.each` is the worst way to loop through the array, may you give me the reason?

Comment: @LeoAref, Edited the answer and added main disadvantages of `.each` over other loops. Is the answer helpful?